# How to draw tropical curves?

Tags: tropical-geometry

In paper [arXiv:1311.2360v3](https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.2360), there are a lot of tropical curves. I want to know how to draw them by using some softwares/algorithms?

Comment: [Here](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~jan/mcs595s14/drawtrop.py) is a Python script which draws random tropical curves. Studying it should give you a good idea on how to plot those.

Comment: You can use something like inkscape. You can also see the source of any arXiv preprint. If you look at the metadata of the PDF files in the articles you linked, you will see that they used fig2dev, a tool which comes from the software xfig.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I read the question more as, how do I generate a plot of a tropical curve given its equation? This amounts to more than just drawing lines, essentially you have to first figure out where to put them.

Comment: @Wojowu I thought OP would also be interested in how the authors of the paper actually drew the lines.